# How to generate an executable of a modular Java app with javapackager?

Tags: windows, java-9, java-module, javapackager

**Environment:** Win10, Oracle JDK 9, Eclipse,  jlink, javapackager

**Context:** I'm trying to generate an executable file with `javapackager` 
**having a java custom runtime image made with `jlink`**, reading the [javapackager documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javapackager.htm#JSWOR719). Not an installable.

Jlink created a zip file, containing all my java class files and resources encapsulated (it means I don't have access to them from System Explorer) + the custom jre. It comes with a .bat launcher to run the app. All works fine.

**Walkthrow:** 1st I found out that there is a `jpackage` utility of OpenJDK [available from OpenJDK14](https://jdk.java.net/jpackage/) to make java modular app executable, which is stil under development. I didn't find any way to work with that.
Later I investigated Inno Setup, but it doesn't fulfil my needs (because I didn't want an installer)
Later I discovered that since Oracle JDK 8 there is `javapackager` tool to generate runnables for each plattform (max, linux, windows..).

I'm not able to make javapackager work.
This is one of various attempts of the command I executed on Windows cmd.

```
javapackager 
-deploy 
    -native exe
    --add-modules myModule,javafx.graphics,javafx.controls 
    --module-path "C:\path\to\javafx-jmods;C:\path\to\target\classes;C:\path\to\more\jmods" 
    -outdir "C:\myApp" 
    -outfile MyApp 
    -appclass myPackage.MyApp 
     -name "MyApp"
```

With the previous command I get the error:

```
Error: No application jars foun
```

So, I realized I was mixing the -deploy command and its options with the -createjar command and its options.

Can someone explain how to generate a .exe with javapackager?

**Edit 1**

Tried jpackage (using jdk 14 with **Wix installer** needed as dependency):

```
jpackage --package-type exe -o outputdir --name myApp --add-modules myapp,javafx.graphics,javafx.controls 
--module-path "C:\path\to\some\jmods;C:\path\to\myTarget;C:\path\to\javafx-sdk-11.0.2plugin" -m myapp/App
```

Output: myApp.1.0.exe. It opens a cmd and a "installer", but does not executes myApp as there is not the custom java runtime environment included.

Comment: I'd recommend https://jdk.java.net/jpackage/ I use it regularly  and it just works for me. What do you mean by: "I didn't find any way to work with that."

Comment: @mipa Because the jpackage download comes with an incomplete version of the OpenJDK14, not with just the jpackage.jar or whatever. I do not how to use it. Could you please add your usage in an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Install the JDK provided with jpackage like any JDK and set your JAVA_HOME to it.

As a preparation for the packaging I have instructed Maven to copy all dependent jar files of the project into the installer/input folder.

Then go to the main folder of your project and call

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/jpackage \
--name yourAppName \
--output installer/output \
--input installer/input \
--main-jar yourAppMain.jar \
--main-class xxx.yyy.yourAppMainClass
```

The result should now be in the installer/output folder.

For more detailed information about the options you can call

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/jpackage --help
```

There is also an option to use a different JDK with the jpackager but this is more advanced.

Comment: I arranged to generate an exe file (adding my app .jmod), but it does nothing because it doesn't have the jre included. The result of jlink is a custom runtime environment, stil don't know how to include that.

Comment: If you followed my above instructions and the prerequisites of the documentation for your platform then you should get an exe WITH an included runtime. If not, there is something wrong with your setup.

Comment: Indeed, the result are 3 folders (app,bin,runtime) with an executable inside bin folder, but is there a way to have an exe file packaging those 3 folders? Tried --package-type command but it makes an installer. I need it just to run.

Comment: Did you try the exe in the bin folder? It should contain everything. On my Mac I only get an app-folder which is the equivalent of an exe-file on windows.